# How to separate Metric by dimension in Google Data Studio?

Tags: data-visualization, looker-studio

How to separate `Sessions` (metric) for each `Page` (dimension) in Google Data Studio?

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved by creating a [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) to group the required section of the URL (in the case below, to capture all characters between the first `/` and and next `/`):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page, "^(/[^/]*)")
```

The [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) above groups values in the `Page` field, as shown below with the `New Page` field:

| Page | New Page |
| --- | --- |
| /example/123/456/789 | /example |
| /example/aboutus/more | /example |
| /example/location/branch | /example |
| /example/staff/department | /example |

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/1b0660ed-bc0c-4b61-9925-918d55905c3f) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]